# Get only new data in dataGridView using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, gridview, datagridview

i am creating an Application in which i want to get only new data from database, suppose i have two records in database table and i select that data in my gridview, then next time when i load data from that table i don't want that previous 2 rows in my grid, i just want new rows if available in database table.

**WHAT I HAVE DONE:**
I have loaded my database table in gridview and counted rows of that grid. then store rows in int variable and next time when i load grid, i again count rows in grid and if there is new row in grid, i transfer these new rows in to new datatable and then assign them to the new grid view. 
in this method i am confused because this works for if only 1 row is newly added since the data is previously loaded.

**WHAT I WANT:**
i want best method to load only the new record in my database so that the previous data will not displayed and processed again.
please help me !

this is the sample code i am using to load data in first dataGridView

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT";
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
}
```

this is the screenshot of table from which i am selecting data.
[http://imgur.com/a/eIaQ6](https://imgur.com/a/eIaQ6)

Comment: what happens when you say **next time** ? a button click, reload?

Comment: why don't u add a condition int he select 'where 'column_name' not in ' a,b,c ' ?  you can get the excluded ids from the grid ? if no ids available execute the default select.

Comment: i mean i have timer of 10 seconds interval, after 10 seconds it again runs the same query and selects all data.

Comment: i don't have any primary key in table, i have same data appearing again and again in table

Comment: i am posting screenshot of my database table

Comment: all columns are the same? even CheckTime?

Comment: checktime can be same too in my case

Comment: @Badiparmagi if i set primary key to checktime field, how can i use that in my fixing my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Add column InsertDate to your table. Maintain lastDataQueriedDate in your code..
Compare these two dates in your query.

Comment: i can't modify design of database table

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll try posting my suggestions or maybe my answer here.

First of all, Try to fix your `Select Query` How can you select the newest data if you use `Select *`?

Second From the answer of `Satish` Better to add new column like `DateInserted` to have a `identifier` or `clue` for all data from your database.

And Lastly, If you can't modify your database design, then try creating a new table that can `relate` or `link` the data of your database and insert your identifier there, like the `DateInserted`.

P.S Try `Satish` answer. It is more easier.